# PJSip and runtime camera permission?

Tags: android, android-camera, pjsip, pjsua2

I am working on video support via pjsip/pjsua2 for android.

My problem is with runtime camera permisson. No matter if I grant the permission, video always fails on

```
vidDevManager().setCaptureOrient
```

https://gist.github.com/ursusursus/972356c40827347360917cd5eda07065

**However, next app launch everything works.**

Also, if I try catch it and restart the library it works

(since permission is now granted)

*My hypothesis is that the library predates runtime permissions and caches something on startup.*

Anyone any idea about this? Has anyone got video working on targetSdk 23+?

Thanks

Comment: Did you add permission in your manifest file?And you need Request permission at runtime.

Comment: I know, I do, and request it, and have it. Everything that is okay, but first call crashes, unless I restart the pjsip library

Comment: Is there some error stack?

Comment: yes, here it is https://gist.github.com/ursusursus/972356c40827347360917cd5eda07065

Comment: what the value of orientation when you invoke `endPoint.vidDevManager().setCaptureOrient()` method.

Comment: `val orientation = pjmedia_orient.PJMEDIA_ORIENT_ROTATE_270DEG
                            vidDevManager.setCaptureOrient(videoCaptureDevice.id, orientation, true)`

Comment: but I think it has to with the permissions as O mentioned. Only after next app restart the same exact code works

Comment: @urSus Yes that's true. There is something with the library. I am using OnePlus 7 Pro which has front pop up camera. I have observed that when I am registering user at time of app initilization, it comes if the permission is granted. So, they might be doing something with camera. I am facing the same issue for runtime camera permission. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after some research, I found the solution.
Once the **Camera** permission is granted, you have to refresh video devices using VideoDeviceManager class.

In my case,

```
MyApp.ep?.vidDevManager()?.refreshDevs()
```

- Here ep stands for EndPoint

It should work now. :)